# Ubuntu doesn't install on hard drive. But it does on a USB stick

Tags: system-installation, usb, hard-drive

I'm pretty new to Linux/Ubuntu in general. I wanted my old PC to run it, because I fell in love with Ubuntu, but I can't seem to install it ..

Okay, so I've got two devices. A USB flash, 8 gigs, and a hard drive, about 160 gigs. I flashed 19.04 to both, and first inserted the hard drive only. At the gnu install screen I chose install. I went through the steps, but in the step where you choose wether you wipe it or dual boot it, I get the partitioning menu, with no disks. Okay, so I disconnected the drive and booted the USB stick. I did everything the same, but I was able to install it, no partitioning menu was needed! The USB stick worked, but was painfully slow.

Also, I tried connecting both. When I boot the USB stick, it doesn't see my hard drive and thus doesn't install there.

Please help. I'm giving up now.

Tl;Dr: Ubuntu can install to USB stick but not to hard drive. Boot from USB stick doesn't detect hard drive and doesn't install there.

Comment: Are you trying to install on to an internal or an external hard drive?  What method(s) did you use to flash the ISO to your thumb drive and hard drive?  Since it's an older PC, are you using the correct ISO for your computer's architecture: ex. i386 or x86/x64?

Comment: @Nmath. I'm not sure what's the difference between internal and external drive. If I unscrew the PC I can remove the drive and replace it, so I guess it's internal. Sorry if I'm wrong. I flashed using Rufus. And I am using the correct architectures. As I said, I was able to install and run Ubuntu on a USB stick, but I can't install it to the drive.

Comment: External hard drives are portable and have their own enclosure and usually their own power supply.  It sounds like you are working with an internal drive.  In that case, is the hard drive showing up in any other operating system?   Is it possible that it's not connected properly to both the motherboard and power supply or is it possible that the drive is dead?  Does it make noise when it starts up?